# How to share state / attributes between directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-directive

How would I go about using an attribute of a directive as an attribute of another directive of the same type?

Before I get to the question I'd like to point out that I'm new to AngularJS and this is part of a learning project. :)

In my case I've got two instances of a datetime-picker directive that I separated from the HTMl to make reusable. One of them is a from-date and one is a to-date.

I would like to use the picked date in the from-date as the minimum available date in the to-date.

However I seem to be unable to somehow get the picked date in the from-date component into the to-date component. And even if I do get it in, it doesn't seem to update, meaning that the to-date component simply defaults back to it's initially set minimum date.

---

This is the directive:

```
<div class="form-group flex center">
    <label class="date-label" for="startdate">{{ ctrl.name }}</label>
    <md-datepicker class="date-value" id="startdate" ng-model="ctrl.today"
                   md-min-date="ctrl.from" md-max-date="ctrl.to"></md-datepicker>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="hours" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Hours
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="hours">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">00</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">01</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">02</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">03</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">04</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">05</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">06</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">07</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">08</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">09</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">10</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">11</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">12</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">13</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">14</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">15</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">16</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">17</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">18</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">19</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">20</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">21</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">22</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">23</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="minutes" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Minutes
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="minutes">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">00</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">01</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">02</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">03</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">04</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">05</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">06</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">07</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">08</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">09</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">10</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">11</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">12</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">13</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">14</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">15</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">16</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">17</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">18</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">19</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">20</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">21</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">22</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">24</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">25</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">26</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">27</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">28</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">29</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">30</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">31</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">32</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">33</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">34</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">35</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">36</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">37</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">38</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">39</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">40</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">41</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">42</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">43</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">44</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">45</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">46</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">47</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">48</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">49</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">50</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">51</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">52</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">53</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">54</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">55</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">56</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">57</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">58</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem">59</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="text-danger" ng-show="shiftForm.plannedStart.$error.required">*Required </span>
</div>
```

and it's js implementation:

```
(function () {

    angular.module("datePicker", [])
        .directive("datePicker", function () {

            return {
                require: 'ngModule',
                restrict: "E",
                scope: {
                    ctrl: '=ctrl'
                },
                templateUrl: "app/views/datepicker.html"
            };
        });
})();
```

And this is how it's used on the "parent":

```
    <form novalidate name="shiftForm" ng-submit="vm.addNewShift()" ng-show="vm.noShiftsFound">
        <div>
            <date-picker ctrl="from"></date-picker>
        </div>
        <div>
            <date-picker ctrl="to"></date-picker>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="shiftForm.$invalid" ng-click="test()"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Important snippet from the parent's JS:

```
let vm = this;  
        vm.myDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        vm.fromDate = moment().subtract(6, 'hours').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");

        vm.today = new Date();
        // for from
        vm.minDate = new Date(
            vm.today.getFullYear(),
            vm.today.getMonth(),
            vm.today.getDate() - 1
        );

        vm.maxDate = new Date(
            vm.today.getFullYear(),
            vm.today.getMonth(),
            vm.today.getDate() + 1
        );

        $scope.from = {
            name: "Planned Start", 
            from: vm.minDate,
            to: vm.maxDate,
            today: vm.today
        };

        $scope.to = {
            name: "Planned Finish",
            from: vm.today,
            to: vm.maxDate,
            today: vm.today
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- Use isolated scope attached to the same parent properties.
- Communicate changes via the parent.
- Implement a communication service to notify subscribers (in this case the other directive) about a change.
- Not my favorite, but use a globally watched variable.

Just my two cents ;)... Happy coding!

Comment: How would I go about communicating the changes via the parent?

Comment: You can use isolated scope to have two-way property binding to properties from the parent scope. Dan Wahlin has written an excellent series of articles about isolated scope: https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope.